# What widgets to use for this custom list item layout

Tags: flutter

Can you provide any advice on the best widgets to use to achieve the below desired list item look?

Here's the list item desired look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vses3.jpg
Here's what my list items look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FkKK.jpg

Below is my code. Can you provide any advice on the best widgets to use to achieve the desired list item look? My biggest issues are the thumbnail widgets not stretching to the same width and height. The image in the thumbnail should just cover the available area.

```
class MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: users.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemExtent: 200, // Need a constant item height of 200
        itemBuilder: (context, i) => new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Divider(
              height: 10.0,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                      flex: 2,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                          child: Image.network(
                            users[i].profile.avatarUrl,
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 3,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            "John Smith",
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              fontSize: 14.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                          const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0)),
                          Text(
                            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt",
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0),
                          ),
                          const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1.0)),
                          Text(
                            '8 Years',
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Icon(
                    Icons.more_vert,
                    size: 16.0,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should limit the size of image. You can do it in several way.

First:

`Image.network(imageUrl, fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,),`

Second:

`width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,`

or just declare height and width for every image.

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap `Padding` widget with `Expanded`
like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',

      home: Scaffold(body: MyScreen()),
    );
  }
}


class MyScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyScreenState createState() => MyScreenState();
}

class MyScreenState extends State<MyScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 10,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemExtent: 200, // Need a constant item height of 200
        itemBuilder: (context, i) => Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Divider(
              height: 10.0,
            ),
            Expanded( // MAGIC IS HERE <--------
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                        flex: 2,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                            child: Image.network(
                              'https://i.picsum.photos/id/896/200/300.jpg?hmac=sgs51khfREKwE_t-0S7LpXpYz2CBlBAoeXTFuoHo-l4',
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 3,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              "John Smith",
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                fontSize: 14.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                            const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0)),
                            Text(
                              "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt",
                              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0),
                            ),
                            const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1.0)),
                            Text(
                              '8 Years',
                              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Icon(
                      Icons.more_vert,
                      size: 16.0,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]